# Enforcing ANSI C89 with clang

Tags: c, clang, c89

I'm trying to make the C compiler `clang` go into ANSI C89 mode but without success.

Here is an example session:

```
$ cat t.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    puts(__FUNCTION__);
    return 0;
}
$ gcc -pedantic -std=c89 -Wall t.c
t.c: In function ‘main’:
t.c:5:7: warning: ISO C does not support ‘__FUNCTION__’ predefined identifier [-Wpedantic]
  puts(__FUNCTION__);
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
$ clang -pedantic -std=c89 -Wall t.c
$ clang --version
clang version 3.8.1-24 (tags/RELEASE_381/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

As you can see, the `clang` command completes with no warning. Is there a command option that I'm missing here?

Comment: That _should_ have worked, I think you may have found a bug in clang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if this specific warning is not emitted by clang, but apparently `-std=c89` does toggle ANSI C89 syntax checking.

For example:

```
inline int foo(int* restrict p)
{
    return *p;
}
```

Will refuse to compile with `-std=c89 -pedantic -Wall`:

> t.c:1:1: error: unknown type name 'inline'
>
> t.c:1:23: error: expected ')'
> int foo(int* restrict p)

But will compile without errors using `-std=c99`.

The non-standard predefined identifiers warning was introduced with GCC 5 (https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/porting_to.html), and apparently clang did not adapt with it.

Comment: Clang also doesn't catch the invalid length modifier `l` in `"%lf"` for the `printf` family of functions. It's valid in C99.